# How to use company-transform to uppercase SQL keywords

Tags: company-mode, sql, capitalization

`company-transform` seems can be used to apply function on candidates.
How to uppercase all SQL keywords which are in company complete candidates?

- only apply this transform function in SQL/NoSQL buffers, like some modes: `redis`, [edbi](https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-edbi), etc.
- use SQL keywords resource from somewhere like [sqlup-mode](https://github.com/Trevoke/sqlup-mode.el).
- show uppercased SQL keywords candidates in company popup menu.